# Angular2 JS Library doesn't work when inside route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an important issue with angular2 and loading JS libraries in combination with routing. Basically, in my project I want to include a JS library that beautifies the button element. But whenever I use routes to navigate through my application, JS library is like not loaded at all.

Example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/FMUcwK1SHnhvhuAgQZ8G?p=preview

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
  Outside Route
</button>
```

The button "**Outside Route**" is working properly. (it has proper behaviour and the ripple effect).

The button "**Inside Route**" is not working properly. (No ripple effect, it is been affected only with CSS files)

Can you tell me, how to make JS libraries work inside routes as well?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here.  The example you posted doesn't have any of the components your question asks about.

Comment: Try now, please. I forgot to fork/save it

Answer (score 0):

You need to (somehow) have a script that is exported properly (i.e. that Angular will understand) and import your module in `app.module.ts`, so that angular can understand to inject it.

I'd suggest you use [Angular2Material](https://github.com/angular/material2), which is the adaptation of Material for Angular.

At it's [Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md) page you are given all the info for how to import it in Angular2.